# How to add custom links in the left pane of Nautilus?

Tags: nautilus

Until recently, one could add custom links to the left pane of [Nautilus](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nautilus_%28file_manager%29) by dragging a folder. It seems this option no longer works (since Ubuntu [10.10](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Ubuntu_releases#Ubuntu_10.10_.28Maverick_Meerkat.29) (Maverick Meerkat) or [11.04](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Ubuntu_releases#Ubuntu_11.04_.28Natty_Narwhal.29) (Natty_Narwhal)). How do I get this to work on a recent version of Ubuntu?

Comment: Seems to be working fine in Natty - press F9 on nautilus to display tree view and drag and drop a folder onto the tree view.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Select the folder you want to link, then go to the top menu bar and select Bookmarks -> Add Bookmark.

When inside the folder that  you want to bookmark, go to the top menu bar and select Bookmarks -> Bookmark this location -- or  <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>.

Comment: In Ubuntu 16, my "Bookmark this location" was greyed out, but  `Ctrl`+`D` still worked.

Comment: There is no more Bookmarks > Add Bookmark in Ubuntu 16 / Files 3.14.3. Instead, you can do this workaround: https://askubuntu.com/a/1051582

Answer (score 5):

You have to go into the folder you want to add, and then press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>D</kbd>, contrary to every other file manager on earth.

Please, apply the [principle of least astonishment](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_least_astonishment) here and go back to something sane. You can remove these by commenting out the corresponding lines in `~/.config/user-dirs.dirs`.

Source: blog post [Ubuntu 12.04: Adding Bookmarks/shortcuts to left sidebar of Nautilus manager](http://naveenubuntu.blogspot.com/2012/05/ubuntu-1204-adding-bookmarksshortcuts.html) (2012-05-05)

Answer (score 2):

You may just drag'n'drop any folder you want to appear in Places bar. This works for remote folders too. Or make a bookmark entry with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> shortcut.

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't seem to work for me.  When I press Ctrl + D the search function opens.  As far as I can see there is nowhere to add a bookmark. When I click on Files Bookmarks I only have the option to edit existing bookmarks, not add a new one.  I am using Ubuntu 13.10.  If anyone has a solution for Ubuntu 13.10 I'd be grateful.

EDIT: I found an answer here: [BookMark13.10](https://askubuntu.com/questions/363302/nautilus-doesnt-allow-adding-removing-bookmarks).  What is a little confusing is that the Bookmark doesn't appear in "Places" but lower down on the left pane under Bookmarks.  At first I didn't see it!

Hope this of some use to someone.

Cheers

Adrian

Comment: I believe you can do this on 14.04 and 14.10. At least you can on my computer that still has 14.10 on it. But on this one with 15.04, you have to go to Bookmarks>Bookmark this Location (or CTRL+D) in the menu bar.

Answer (score 0):

Drag and drop to create Bookmarks doesn't work for some items like symlinks.

A workaround is to create a temporary bookmark by drag and drop to the left sidebar "New Bookmark" (any item, it doesn't matter). Then press `ctrl+B` to edit the Bookmark's Location manually.