# How can I add a dropbox folder option under my "Places" in Nautilus

Tags: nautilus, dropbox, places

Like windows, when you download dropbox it places a folder in the library list.  I'm wondering if I'm able to similarly add dropbox under "Places".  Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: I dont currently have my Ubuntu 14.04 laptop with me, However, I do know that I was able to do this... Not sure if its bc I backed up my settings with Deja Backup from 13 and restored them and it just did it for me, or if I made the changes myself (can't remember).  But I do know that I have it there on 14.04.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to add custom links in the left pane of Nautilus?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/64010/how-to-add-custom-links-in-the-left-pane-of-nautilus)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

There multiple alternative options:

- Pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> adds a bookmark to the folder you're in (tested under Ubuntu 12.04 & 13.04). For Ubuntu 14.04, use the *Files* application (a. k. a. *Nautilus*) to navigate to the folder you want bookmarked, then press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>, the same with going to the top menu bar and selecting *Bookmarks → Bookmark this location*.
- Select the folder that you want added to bookmarks, then go to the top menu bar and select *Bookmarks → Add Bookmark*.
- You can add them editing by `~/.gtk-bookmarks`. Say you want to add `~/Software` and `~/Ebooks` folder under *Places*. Just add the following line at the end of `~/.gtk-bookmarks`:

  ```
  file:///home/my_username/Software  
  file:///home/my_username/Ebooks
  ```

Try it out and let me know. Hope it helps.

Comment: One can only make use of the **Bookmarks** menu both to add the current folder and also to manage the bookmarks.

Comment: Under Bookmarks is not under Places.

Answer (score 1):

To edit the actual "Places" group, edit the `~/.config/user-dirs.dirs` file and add your directories in there.

The thing is, that file is automatically generated when you log-on by the `xdg-user-dirs-update` program. To prevent it from overriding your changes, run the following command:

```bash
$ echo "enabled=False" > ~/.config/user-dirs.conf
```

For a more detailed explanation, and support for other versions of Ubuntu, see this page: http://choorucode.com/2010/07/25/how-to-add-or-remove-places-entries-in-nautilus/

Comment: This file doesn't exist in 14.04 and the link is now broken.

Answer (score 1):

I have Ubuntu 14.04 with latest nautilus/files 3.12.2. I have the same problem, some files only have bookmark with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd>, I try to add but it won't work.

The solution is press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>.

Hope it helps other

Answer (score 0):

I am using jammy 22.04.03 and I fixed this problem by navigating to the Dropbox folder and dragging the Dropbox folder icon over the 'Places" in the left panel. This added it to the Places list.