# How to add Dropbox to Nautilus left bar

Tags: nautilus, icons, dropbox

I use Dropbox a lot, so I would like a way to add its folder to Nautilus' left bar.

As far as I know, we can add the folder Dropbox to bookmarks, but I would like it to be at the top, near `Downloads` and `Images` folder.

So the question is: **How to add Dropbox to Nautilus' left bar, near Download and Images folders**?

Comment: Another way to do it (other than Eduardo's answer) is to add your Dropbox folder to your "Bookmarks" in Nautilus; go to the Dropbox folder and then press Ctrl-D. See http://askubuntu.com/questions/389541/how-can-i-add-a-dropbox-folder-option-under-my-places-in-nautilus

Answer (score 0):

If you use Dropbox a lot, it may be used as your default Documents folder.

You can change _XDG_DOCUMENTS_DIR_ to point it to Dropbox:

Edit your `~/.config/user-dirs.dirs` and change the line to:

```
XDG_DOCUMENTS_DIR="$HOME/Dropbox"
```

Restart your session, and check it:

[image: The Dropbox folder will be used as your Documents folde]