# Access files from my nas

Tags: networking, mount, samba, sharing

So I switched from XP to Ubuntu. Install was pretty easy, partly because I have all my data on a nas.

The very first I needed to do with my new Ubuntu environment was to send a file from my nas to somebody by using wetransfer. Shouldn't be that difficult, should it?

So I browsed to the network, double clicked on my nas it's share, authenticated, et voila. There is my data.

Started the browser, went to wetransfer.com and clicked to select the file. ehm, hu? There is NO way to browse to the share on my nas?????????

That was two days ago, and I still can not browse to my data from with an application. I've googled and googled, and read about gfvs-mount, mount, smbnetfs, tried them all but no luck.

What am I doing wrong?? this shouldn't be that difficult, should it?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: You need to setup auto mount your NAS. This will depend on the brand and kind of NAS and the protocols it supports. If you **edit the original question** add your NAS make and model and the protocols it supports, someone may be able to help you. See http://askubuntu.com/search?q=auto+mount+NAS for a list of questions on this topic.

Comment: you need to automount the NAS, see here: http://askubuntu.com/a/429496/72216

Comment: As user68186 kind of implied, you don't really tell us what NAS you are using, how you browse to it or authenticate, (SMB?) etc. Those details will help us figure out whats wrong.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to do this is to add your NAS to your file dialog. From there you will be able to access your NAS directories. To do this you need to bookmark the directory in the NAS for the filemanager to remember the location.

Browse to the directory in the file manager, then bookmark it:

- [How to add custom links in the left pane of Nautilus?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/64010/how-to-add-custom-links-in-the-left-pane-of-nautilus?rq=1)

Now when you go to wetransfer.com and click the upload button the file dialog will have the right bookmark on it, click on it, select the file, and that should be it.

To make this work permanently follow these instructions:

- [How to create a Bookmark that opens a Network shared folder](https://askubuntu.com/questions/429493/how-to-create-a-bookmark-that-opens-a-network-shared-folder/429496#429496)